# Need a regex for int_int_int

Tags: php, regex

I have data in the following type:

```
168_1523968382107_4841
16_152396858188_270
18_15239683821073_15292
some_text_here
anothertext
newtext_backup_3
```

I need regex to identify first three.

So far I know that the integer can be found using

```
\b\d+\b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the RegEx [`(\d+_){2}\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/ytzDI4/1)

- `\d+_` matches 1 or more digit followed by a `_`
- `{2}` repeats the preceding match twice
- `\d+` matches 1 or more digit

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/ytzDI4/1)

---

If you want to get every `int` as a result of your RegEx, use [`(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/ytzDI4/2)

[**Demo #2.**](https://regex101.com/r/ytzDI4/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)
```